# How To Use SharedPreference value stored in one activity to another activity

Tags: android

My Code is:

```
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MYPREF'USERID",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int uid = myPrefs.getInt("USERID", 0);
```

I want to use USERID in another two activities for fetching records
Please help me how to do 
Thank You

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What's wrong with using exactly the same code in another activity?

Comment: sorry m very much new in android i dont have any idea how to do :( :( please help me. i used the above code in two activities but it gives log cat error java null pointer exception

Comment: @pooja: refer this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set values in preference as follows

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt ("USERID", 0);
        editor.commit();
```

and you can retrieve the data form preference as

```
final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
final int userId= pref.getInt("USERID", -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get SharedPreferences all around your application by using:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You also want to put your values in this global sharedPreference.